# How to recursively aggregate Treelike(hierarchical) data using Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given a dataset representing a Treelike hierarchical structure e.g.:

```
+-------+--------+
|childId|parentId|
+-------+--------+
|      1|       0|
|      2|       1|
|      3|       1|
|      4|       2|
|      5|       2|
|      6|       2|
|      7|       3|
|      8|       3|
|      9|       3|
|     10|       4|
+-------+--------+
```

How can it be aggregated as follows using `Spark`? So that, for each node of the Tree, all its children, grand-children and so on(till leaves) are can be aggregated:

```
+--------+--------------------+-----+
|parentId|            children|count|
+--------+--------------------+-----+
|       1|[15, 9, 16, 2, 17...|   16|
|       3|[15, 9, 16, 17, 7...|    7|
|       4|    [12, 13, 10, 11]|    4|
|       7|    [15, 16, 17, 14]|    4|
|       2|[12, 13, 5, 6, 10...|    7|
|       0|[15, 9, 1, 16, 2,...|   17|
+--------+--------------------+-----+
```

A sample data file can be found [here](https://github.com/newroyker/SparkTreeApp/blob/master/data/tree/edges.csv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
  case class Edge(childId: Int, parentId: Int)

  val edges: Dataset[Edge] = spark.read
    .option("header", value = true)
    .option("inferSchema", value = true)
    .csv("data/tree/edges.csv")
    .as[Edge]
```

Implement a recursive algorithm like BFS as follows:

```
def bfs(edges: Dataset[Edge]): Dataset[Edge] = {
    @tailrec
    def helper(n: Dataset[Edge], accum: Dataset[Edge]): Dataset[Edge] = {
      val newN = n.as("n")
        .join(edges.as("plus1"), $"n.childId" === $"plus1.parentId")
        .select($"plus1.childId", $"n.parentId")
        .as[Edge]

      if (newN.count() == 0) accum else helper(newN, accum.union(newN))
    }

    edges.cache()

    helper(edges, edges)
  }
```

Then, invoke as follows:

```
bfs(edges)
    .groupBy($"parentId")
    .agg(
      collect_set($"childId").alias("children"),
      countDistinct($"childId").alias("count")
    )
```

Complete Scala implementation [here](https://github.com/newroyker/SparkTreeApp/blob/master/src/main/scala/TreeApp.scala#L34-L56). Not sure if there are other easier, more elegant ways to accomplish this.